# Indexing Numpy array with list and tuple gives different results?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((5,5))
a[[0,1]] = 1     #(list of indices)
print('results with list based indexing\n', a)

a = np.zeros((5,5))
a[(0,1)] = 1   #(tuple of indices)
print('results with tuple based indexing\n',a)
```

Result:

```
results with list based indexing
 [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

results with tuple based indexing
[[  0.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

As you must have noticed, indexing array with list gave a different result than with tuple of same indices.
I'm using python3 with numpy version 1.13.3

What is the fundamental difference in indexing a numpy array with list and tuple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*By design.*  Numpy's getitem and setitem syntax does not duck-type, because the different types are used to support [different features](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).  This is just a plain old `__setitem__`:

```
a[(0,1)] = 1
```

It's the same as doing `a[0,1] = 1`.  In both cases, ndarray's setitem receives two arguments: a tuple for the index `(0, 1)` and the value `1`.

```
a[[0,1]] = 1
```

This is a special case of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting).  It would usually be written `a[0:2] = 1`, but you could also slice/mutate other rows for example `a[[0,1,3]]`.  The scalar `1` gets "stretched" across all columns of rows 0 and 1 in the assignment.

Comment: Got it thanks, I also thought of it by another way, writing it down as a answer

Comment: The list case could also be written a `a[0,1], :]`.  This makes it clearer, to humans, that the list is selecting two whole rows.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried following cases in terminal.

```
a[[0],[1]] = 1
a[(0),(1)] = 1
a[(0,),(1,)] = 1
```

All of them are equivalent to `a[0,1] = 1`. 
What I understood from this is that, **Numpy is expecting N different sequences of integers for indexing N dimensions of array.**

Meaning, indexing array as `a[[ 0,1 ]]` results in `a[ [0,1], :]`.

`[0,1]` is taken as a one sequence of integers to access first dimension of the array and since no indexing is mentioned for remaining dimension it is taken as`:`by default which results in `a[[0,1],:]`.

Answer by [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992706/indexing-numpy-array-with-list-and-tuple-gives-different-results/48992851#48992851) gave me a direction for this thought.

Cheers!